# Solving pulley system using $\Sigma T.x=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

I found this on the internet

Why should  $\Sigma T.x=0$ hold?

Source: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-pulley-constraint-problems

Comment: Read about why work done by tension is zero

Answer (score 1):

This basically means the word done by tension is always zero. $\Sigma T \cdot x = 0$

This is because the tension throughout an ideal string is same at every point and the displacement is also same but at the ends of the string the direction of tension is opposite which cancels out so work done is 0

Answer (score 0):

starting with Newton equations

$$ \mathbf M\,\ddot{\mathbf{R}}=\mathbf{F}+\mathbf{F}_C\tag 1$$

where $~\mathbf{F}_C~$ are the constraint forces.

to eliminate the constraint forces you use the D'Alembert's principle

$$\delta \mathbf R\cdot  \mathbf{F}_C=0$$

you first example

Newton

$$m_1\,a_1=T-m_1\,g\\
m_2\,a_2=2\,T-m_2\,g$$

and the constraint equation

$$x_1+2\,x_2=0\quad,\Rightarrow
a_1+2\,a_2=0$$

you obtain 3 equations for the unknows $~a_1,a_2,T$

choose $~a_2~$ to be the generalized coordinate , you obtain from the constraint equation $~a_1=-2\,a2~$ from here and the Newton equation you can eliminate the constraint force T

---

the equation of motion

$$  \mathbf J^T\,M\,\mathbf J\ddot{\mathbf{q}}=\mathbf J^T\,\mathbf{F}$$

with $~\mathbf R=\mathbf R(\mathbf q)~$
and $~\mathbf J=\frac{\partial \mathbf R}{\partial \mathbf q}~$